# Why does Initialising a struct causes a different local variable to be nulled?

Tags: c, struct, variable-assignment

I'm trying to implement a linked list in C. Refer to the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Node {
    int has_value;
    int value;
    struct Node* next;
};

typedef struct Node Node;

void push(Node* node, int value) {
    while(1) {
        if (!node->has_value) {
            node->value = value;
            node->has_value = 1;
            return;
        }
        if (node->next) {
            node = node->next;
            continue;
        }
        else {
            Node new = {};
            new.value = value;
            new.has_value = 1;
            node->next = &new;
            return;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    Node node = {};

    push(&node, 10);
    push(&node, 20);
    push(&node, 30);

    Node second = *node.next;
    Node third = *second.next;

    printf("%i\n", node.value);
    printf("%i\n", second.value);
    printf("%i\n", third.value);
}
```

I expected `node`, `second`, and `third` to have values of 10, 20, and 30, respectively. Instead, `second` and `third` are identical, both with the same value of 30 and the same `next` pointer. I did some debugging with gdb, and stepped inside the `push(&node, 30)`. It does one `continue` as expected, but then on the second iteration through the while loop, inside the `else` clause, something really weird happens. Before we initialise the `new` node, `node` has a value of 20, since it is the second node. Then right after the `Node new = {};`, if I print out the value of `node` again, it is now null: `{.has_value = 0, value = 0, next = 0x0}`. I have no idea why this happens. `node` is a different variable from `new`, so why does initialising `new` overwrite the value of `node`, a different local variable?? I've tested that if I don't call `push` a third time, and instead initialise a new node and set the `next` property of the second node manually, everything works as expected. What's going on here?

I am compiling with `gcc main.c`.

Comment: `{ Node new = {};` ... `node->next = &new;  return; }`  - think about when `new` will be destroyed

Comment: @M.M right, I guess it would be destroyed at the end of the else clause, right? But why does `node` get overwritten immediately? And it's not just the `next` that gets overwritten, the `value` and `has_value` both also get nulled. I don't see why that would happen just because `new` is destroyed?

Comment: And also the exact same thing happens if I allocate `new` on the heap instead. So, replacing `Node new = {};` with `Node* p = malloc(sizeof(Node)); Node new = *p;`

Comment: `Node new = *p;` does not set `new` to point to the space allocated by `malloc` or to refer to that space. It sets `new` to be a copy of the node in that space, but that space is uninitialized, so it is not putting anything useful in `new`. The node `new` remains an automatic object whose lifetime ends when the `return;` is executed. You need `Node *new = malloc(sizeeof *new);`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil thank you! That makes sense, and switching to this approach fixed it. If you want to post an answer, I can accept it.